# MySQL SELECT / QUERY - How can I select all datarecords by a string independet of write art?

Tags: php

I have follow php code:

```
$query  = "SELECT  * FROM catalog   WHERE   Keywords  LIKE  '%$Keywords%'" ;
```

where Keywords contains a string in the greek language ( as you know greek words have an accent (like: ξυλουργεία νομού Ηλείας). I want to search the column of the mysql-column independet of the writting art of the words that Keywords contains. Those words are given from visitors of my site. The visitor can write as follow those key words: ΞΥΛΟΥΡΓΕΙΑ ΝΟΜΟΥ ΗΛΕΙΑΣ, or Ξυλουργεία νομού Ηλείας etc.

Thnx

it would be for me much better if you could answer my question in the German or Greek languange.

Answer (score 1):

USE collation that ends in _ci (which means case insensitive) and make sure the field in database is not binary (_bin collations as well as fields that are marked as binary are compared case-sensitive)